# Constraints under which $\rho(x, y) = |x - y|^d$ satisfies the triangle inequality

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Is it possible to prove by purely algebraic means (without straightaway resorting to counterexamples) that $\rho(x, y) = |x - y|^d$ does not satisfy the triangle inequality $\rho(x, y) \leq \rho(x, z) + \rho(z, y)$ for $d = 2$? And under what constraints on $x, y, z$ does it satisfy the inequality? I'm trying to see why $\rho$ cannot be a valid metric on $\mathbb R$.

Bonus question: For what other values $d \in \mathbb R$ does $\rho$ not satisfy the triangle inequality.

Comment: What do you have in mind when you talk about a proof that doesn't resort to counterexamples?

Comment: I guess I mean algebraically finding the set of all counterexamples and not proof by a single counterexample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inequality is equivalent to $(a+b)^{d} \leq a^{d}+b^{d}$ for $a, b \geq 0$. Putting $a=b=1$ we see that $2^{d} \leq 2$. Hence $d \leq 1$ is a necessary condition. For any $d \in (0,1]$ the inequality is valid. This can be proved by observing that $(a+b)^{d}-a^{d}-b^{d}$ is  decreasing function of $a$ and vanishes when $a=0$.

When $d<0$, $|x-y|^{d}$ is not even defined when $x=y$ so it does not yield a metric. $d=0$ is left to you.

Comment: Thanks! Few questions: why can't it be valid for $d < 0$ too? Also, why do we only have to show that it is a decreasing function only for $a$ and not for $b$?

Comment: I guess we also have to show that $(a+b)^d - a^d - b^d$ is positive for all $a, b > 0$.

Comment: I notice that $|x - y|^d$ for $x = y$ is not defined if $d < 0$, thanks. But I'd still be interested to know for which $d < 0$, the inequality $(a+b)^d - a^d - b^d > 0$ holds

Comment: For $d<0$ see my edit. For the proof in the case $0<d\leq 1$ you can either maximize w.r.t $a$ or w.r.t $b$. the choice is yours.

Comment: Ummm, but don't we still have to show that $(a + b)^d - a^d - b^d > 0$ for all $a, b \in \mathbb R^{+}$ (and $d \in (0, 1]$) before showing that the function is decreasing and vanishes when either $a = 0$ or $b = 0$?

Comment: The derivative w.r.t $a$ is $d(a+b)^{d-1}-da^{d-1}$ which is negative when $d\leq 1$..